# Can't save new CMS/Pages because URL Validation

Tags: cms, url, validation, key

I'm on Magento 1.9.0.1 and everything is working well but if i try to generate Content via CMS/Pages/New Page i´ve got a big problem.

When i fill out the forms for a new Page I get this error under the URL Key Field in the "Page Information" Area:

Please enter a valid URL Key. For example "example-page", "example-page.html" or "anotherlevel/example-page".

I can't save this page due to this error. Even if I try to edit an existing page i get this error.

Do I have to define special URL Keys anywhere? What can I do?

Thanks

Tamás

Comment: What is the key you're attempting to input that causes this error?

Comment: It was an Uppercase Letter... when i write everything without uppercase Letters it will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, I had this last week when upgrading a 1.5 shop to 1.9.0.1. The first character of the URL-keys of some CMS-pages had became capitalized, which fails the JS validation... Does your input contain uppercase chars?

Comment: Raaaage-ento strikes again.  Uppercase letters...